# How to get latest SVN tag in Jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins

I would need to checkout the latest SVN tag to my Jenkins build job workspace. With tag I mean the copied folder, often used to create milestones.

I read from some stackoverflow question that one could get the latest e.g. with

```
"svn ls .../path/to/repo/tags | tail -n 1"
```

, but I don't think this can be given to Jenkins SCM field. I believe Jenkins requires the exact location in SVN. Any ideas? I would believe this is actually quite a common requirement in large projects....

Answer (score 3):

Suggested answer is *almost correct* on the assumption that:

- Incremental alpha-numeric permanent naming scheme used
- BASE path somehow added to result of pipe (ls output **relative path** to tags/)

If the above conditions are **not fulfilled**, you have to use slightly different command and some piece of business logic "Latest tag have the highest revision number"

```
>svn ls -v http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/tags/
     22 lazybadg              июл 17  2010 ./
     11 lazybadg              июл 17  2010 1.0/
     22 lazybadg              июл 17  2010 1.1/
```

output of *this* ls can be gawk'ed, most recent revision found in $1, relative path of needed tag in $6 (or $5, I'm lazy to test)

Comment: Hey Lazy Badger, thanks for the answer. I believe that script works, but the problem is how to implement it into jenkins. One cannot add that line into the Jenkins SCM field, and I haven't found a section on how to do it "dynamically"

Comment: @user1340582: if you can execute external programs inside Jenkins task, then shell-script|bat-file can be written (I know nothing about Jenkins specially)

Comment: I would also suggest ignoring the Jenkins SCM field and instead using a script which you call as a first Build-step